# Enterprise Magento2.3.2 Unable to get Category Image Url Programmatically

Tags: magento2.3.2, category-image

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category
    */
    protected $categoryHelper;

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository
    */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $selectedCatId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('subCatId');

        $categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($selectedCatId);

        var_dump($categoryObj->getImageUrl());
            exit;
    }
}
```

I have set the image in admin for category Id: 358:
[image]

Below is the output of print_r($categoryObj->getData());

```
<pre>Array(
[entity_id] => 358
[attribute_set_id] => 12
[parent_id] => 2
[created_at] => 2019-08-05 11:43:07
[updated_at] => 2019-08-05 12:08:06
[path] => 1/2/358
[position] => 22
[level] => 2
[children_count] => 34
[row_id] => 358
[created_in] => 1
[updated_in] => 2147483647
[store_id] => 1
[abacos_codigo] => 
[abacos_codigo_pai] => 
[all_children] => 
[automatic_sorting] => 
[available_sort_by] => 
[category_zone] => 
[children] => 
[custom_apply_to_products] => 0
[custom_design] => 
[custom_design_from] => 
[custom_design_to] => 
[custom_layout_update] => 
[custom_use_parent_settings] => 0
[default_sort_by] => 
[description] => 
[display_mode] => PRODUCTS
[filter_price_range] => 
[hide_desktop] => 0
[image] => 
[include_in_menu] => 0
[is_active] => 1
[is_anchor] => 0
[landing_page] => 
[meta_description] => 
[meta_keywords] => 
[meta_title] => 
[mobile_img] => 
[name] => Start
[nav-image] => 
[page_layout] => category-full-width
[path_in_store] => 
[thumbnail] => 
[url_key] => start
[url_path] => start
[weltpixel_category_url] => 
[weltpixel_category_url_newtab] => 0
[weltpixel_mm_bottom_block] => 
[weltpixel_mm_bottom_block_cms] => 
[weltpixel_mm_bottom_block_type] => none
[weltpixel_mm_columns_number] => 4
[weltpixel_mm_column_width] => auto
[weltpixel_mm_display_mode] => sectioned
[weltpixel_mm_left_block] => 
[weltpixel_mm_left_block_cms] => 
[weltpixel_mm_left_block_type] => none
[weltpixel_mm_mob_hide_allcat] => 0
[weltpixel_mm_right_block] => 
[weltpixel_mm_right_block_cms] => 
[weltpixel_mm_right_block_type] => none
[weltpixel_mm_top_block] => 
[weltpixel_mm_top_block_cms] => 
[weltpixel_mm_top_block_type] => none
```

)

Comment: The issue was having in Enterprise Magento. Its been fixed after reindexing.

Comment: try print_r($categoryObj->getImageUrl());

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code in your controller. It maybe helpful for you :

```
protected $categoryFactory


public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    .....
){
    .....
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    .....
}

public function execute()
{
    $selectedCatId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('subCatId');
    $categoryObj = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($selectedCatId);
    echo $categoryObj->getImageUrl();
}
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Its not working. If returns null array.

Comment: It seems like you didn't set image in that category.

Comment: Please make sure that image set in that appropriate category.

Comment: Please check my edited question with image screenshot of Admin.

Comment: remove generated and clean cache please.

Comment: If you want to check in DB that entry exist or not. Then, you can find in catalog_category_entity_varchar table in attribute_id 48

Comment: Removing generated cache clean its already done each time when I render the data. I have added array output above. There is no Image found. Also I have created two other attributes they also not showing in data. The same code is working fine in Magento2.3.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97135/discussion-between-ankita-patel-and-dinesh-rajput).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     protected $_storeManager;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            parent::__construct($data);
        }

        $categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
        $categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore()); //categories from current store will be fetched

        foreach ($categories as $category){
            print_r($category->getImageUrl());
        }
die('end');
```